# Is it possible to have an inconsistent branch/tag with SVN due to concurrent commit action?

Tags: svn, branch, commit, tagging

I'm trying to understand whether subversion has its own mechanisms for regulating concurrent user activities on the trunk (IE a branch/tag action and a commit action happening at the same time) or if it's up to the users to sync between themselves before acting on the trunk.

I've been trying to find documentation about this on the net but haven't been able to come up with something, so I appreciate if someone can enlighten me on the topic.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN takes care of it. SVN actions are atomic, which means that if it fails for some reason, then action will not be performed at all, and repository state will stay the same as before the action.

Comment: First off thank you. I should've actually thought of it by myself, since it would've been really dangerous (to the point of making SVN pretty useless) otherwise. But better safe than sorry, so thank you for your reply and thus for having solved my doubt!